# Seperating characters in dfm object R

Tags: r, regex, quanteda

all,

I have imported the sotu corpus from `quanteda` in R. I am somewhat new to dfm objects and am wanting to separate the `doc_id` column to give me a `name` and a `year` column. If this was a tibble, this code works:

```
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.corpora)
library(tidyverse)
sotu <- as_tibble(data_corpus_sotu)
sotusubsetted <- sotu %>%
   separate(doc_id, c("name","year"),"-")
```

However, since I am new with dfm and regex, I am not sure if there is an equivalent process if I load in the data as:

```
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.corpora)
library(tidyverse)
sotu <- corpus(data_corpus_sotu)
sotudfm <- dfm(sotu)
```

Is there some equivalent way to do this with dfm objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest method is also one that will work for any core quanteda object, meaning equally for a corpus, tokens, or dfm object.  These involve using the accessor functions, not addressing the internals of the corpus or dfm objects directly, which is strongly discouraged.  You can do that, but your code could break in the future if those object structures are changed.  In addition, our accessor functions are generally also the most efficient method.

For this task, you want to use the `docnames()` functions or accessing the document IDs, and this works for the corpus as well as for the dfm.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.2

data("data_corpus_sotu", package = "quanteda.corpora")

data.frame(doc_id = docnames(data_corpus_sotu[1:5])) %>%
  tidyr::separate(doc_id, c("name", "year"), "-")
##         name  year
## 1 Washington  1790
## 2 Washington 1790b
## 3 Washington  1791
## 4 Washington  1792
## 5 Washington  1793

data.frame(doc_id = docnames(dfm(data_corpus_sotu[1:5]))) %>%
  tidyr::separate(doc_id, c("name", "year"), "-")
##         name  year
## 1 Washington  1790
## 2 Washington 1790b
## 3 Washington  1791
## 4 Washington  1792
## 5 Washington  1793
```

You could also have taken this from the "President" docvar field and the "Date":

```r
data.frame(
  name = data_corpus_sotu$President,
  year = lubridate::year(data_corpus_sotu$Date)
) %>%
  head()
##         name year
## 1 Washington 1790
## 2 Washington 1790
## 3 Washington 1791
## 4 Washington 1792
## 5 Washington 1793
## 6 Washington 1794
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do exactly what you want, albeit it might break some operations in quanteda that will look for *docid_* in `sotudfm@docvars`, the data frame that stores the documents relational data. For instance, it will break any filtering by `sotudfm@Dimnames$docs`, which is where the dimension names of the documents are listed.

```
sotudfm@docvars <- sotudfm@docvars %>% separate(col = docid_, c("name","year"),"-")

> sotudfm@docvars %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 241 x 10
    docname_         name       year  segid_ FirstName President  Date       delivery type  party      
   <chr>            <chr>      <chr>  <int> <chr>     <chr>      <date>     <fct>    <fct> <fct>      
     1 Washington-1790  Washington 1790       1 George    Washington 1790-01-08 spoken   SOTU  Independent
     2 Washington-1790b Washington 1790b      1 George    Washington 1790-12-08 spoken   SOTU  Independent
     3 Washington-1791  Washington 1791       1 George    Washington 1791-10-25 spoken   SOTU  Independent
     4 Washington-1792  Washington 1792       1 George    Washington 1792-11-06 spoken   SOTU  Independent
     5 Washington-1793  Washington 1793       1 George    Washington 1793-12-03 spoken   SOTU  Independent
     6 Washington-1794  Washington 1794       1 George    Washington 1794-11-19 spoken   SOTU  Independent
     7 Washington-1795  Washington 1795       1 George    Washington 1795-12-08 spoken   SOTU  Independent
     8 Washington-1796  Washington 1796       1 George    Washington 1796-12-07 spoken   SOTU  Independent
     9 Adams-1797       Adams      1797       1 John      Adams      1797-11-22 spoken   SOTU  Federalist 
    10 Adams-1798       Adams      1798       1 John      Adams      1798-12-08 spoken   SOTU  Federalist
```

Comment: This may be my ignorance, but is there a way to do this while also creating an object with the actual text from the SOTU's?

Comment: Perhaps you want to buid a new corpus? See https://tutorials.quanteda.io/basic-operations/corpus/corpus/
You might also want to get two new variables in the docvars table, without eliminating docid_. For isstance, you could use sub("^.*-", "", docid_) to retrieve just the year into a new varaible/signal.

Comment: The code you had above worked when I adjusted the code to use `docname_` instead which was a variable along with `docid_` in `sotudfm@docvars`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
sotudfm@docvars <- sotudfm@docvars %>% 
    separate(col = docname_, c("name","year"),"-")
```

This kept the `doc_id` intact when I ran

```
head(sotudfm, 10)
```

It appears that `docid_` and `docname_` are identical.